# Como apagar a primeira linha de um arquivo SQL megapesado?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, shell, banco-de-dados

Tenho um arquivo SQL "mega pesado" que não abre nem no sublime, nem no bloco de notas e nem no gedit. Só preciso apagar a primeira linha `Use nome_database;` para poder fazer a importação através do workbench ou linha de comando do mysql no terminal:
 `mysql -hmeu_servidor -uroot -psenha banconovo < path/meuarquivo.sql`.

O problema é que o nome do banco é outro, por isso, está dando um erro, ele não encontra a base. Alguém tem uma alternativa para apagar essa linha sem precisar abrir o arquivo?

Pode ser via script `edit.sh` ou via PHP `edit.php`. Ou alguma sugestão melhor...

Comment: "Mega pesado" dá quanto em bytes?

Comment: ele pesa 1.5GB... ta foda. recebi assim do cliente.

Comment: Você pode usar um editor hexadecimal como alternativa. o HxD é muito bom.

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/ - faça um backup antes de experimentar. Fica a sugestão de não alterar o tamanho das strings. Por exemplo, se o nome for mais curto, complete com espaços fora das aspas. Se for mais comprido, precisa fazer um pouco de contorcionismo...

Comment: Eu uso linux... tem uma versão para ubuntu?

Comment: Esse tipo de editor costuma ter de monte, só não vou saber de cara o nome de algum pra linux. Se vc tiver pratica com o terminal, pode fazer usando o modo texto, até tem mais ferramentas pra isso.

Comment: Não testei com o "vi" ainda.

Comment: Só pra constar, se um dia precisar, o `vim`, tem o `:%!xxd` pra entrar em modo hexa (atualmente o vi é atalho pro vim em quase todos os sistemas) - mas comentei de curiosidade, pq se abrir com o `vim` nao precisa usar o modo hexa nesse caso específico, claro.

Comment: experimente isso pelo terminal: `sed '1d' original.sql > modificado.sql` (manual http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

Comment: funcionou aqui, com o "vi", obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só para constar, a maneira que consegui, foi entrando no terminal, e digitando:

`vi arquivo_megapesado.sql`

Dentro do editor `vi`, digitei: `i`, para poder editar o arquivo, apaguei o trecho que queria, depois apertei a tecla `esc` para sair do modo de edição e digitei `:wq!` para salvar e sair do editor.

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias maneiras de se fazer isso no Linux:

1) Usando `tail` (removendo primeira linha):

```
$ tail -n +2 arquivo.sql > /tmp/arqtmp.sql; mv /tmp/arqtmp.sql arquivo.sql
```

2) Usando `sed` (removendo primeira linha):

```
$ sed -i '1d' arquivo.sql
```

3) Usando `grep` (detectando a linha com o conteúdo e removendo):

```
$ grep -v 'Use nome_database;' arquivo.sql > /tmp/arqtmp.sql; mv /tmp/arqtmp.sql arquivo.sql
```

Espero ter ajudado!